# Part 2: Send HTTP request for each row in Excel table

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, http

This script was previously reviewed here: [Send HTTP request for each row in Excel table (Part 1)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244387/send-http-request-for-each-row-in-excel-table-part-1)

I've made the changes that were suggested in the Code Review answers as well as added a few of my own.

The code is quite a bit different now. Are there any more improvements that should be made?

---

> Description:
>
> 1. A custom function concatenates columns with parameters into the `Concatenated Variables` column.
> 2. Loops through each row in the table where `Load? = y`
> 3. Sends an HTTP request to an external system using the value in the `URL` column.
> 4. Returns a message (created, updated, or problem/error) and stores it in the `Message` column.
>
> [image]

---

New code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const tblName = "tblData"
Public Const colNameLoad = "Load?"
Public Const colNameMessage = "Message"
Public Const colNameURL = "URL"
Public Const colNameTimestamp = "Message Timestamp"

Function CodeName() As Worksheet
Set CodeName = DataSheet
End Function

Public Sub LoadRecords()
    Application.CalculateFull
    Dim message As String, response As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    'Keep an eye on unecessary calls to the ConcatVars function.
    With CodeName.ListObjects(tblName)
        .ListColumns(colNameMessage).Range.Interior.Color = rgbWhite
        .ListColumns(colNameMessage).Range.Font.Color = rgbLightGrey
        For n = 1 To .ListRows.Count
            If UCase(.ListColumns(colNameLoad).DataBodyRange(n).Value) = "Y" Then
                response = GetHTTP(.ListColumns(colNameURL).DataBodyRange(n).Value)
                .ListColumns(colNameMessage).DataBodyRange(n) = response
                .ListColumns(colNameMessage).DataBodyRange(n).Font.Color = rgbBlack
                .ListColumns(colNameTimestamp).DataBodyRange(n) = Now()
            
                With .ListColumns(colNameMessage).DataBodyRange(n)
                    message = Left(response, 7)
                    .Interior.Color = Switch(message = "Created", rgbLightGreen, message = "Updated", rgbSkyBlue, message = "Problem", rgbYellow, True, rgbOrangeRed)
                End With
            
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String

On Error GoTo ConnectionError:

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
        GetHTTP = VBA.StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function
ConnectionError:
GetHTTP = "Problem with URL or server: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Function

Function ConcatVars(RowNum As Integer) As String
    Dim Column As ListColumn
    Dim s As String

    For Each Column In CodeName.ListObjects(tblName).ListColumns
        If Column.Name Like "f_*" Then
            s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, "&", "") _
                & Mid(Column.Name & "=" & Column.Range.Cells(RowNum).Value, 3)
        End If
    Next
    ConcatVars = s
End Function
```

---

I have a follow-up question here: [Create or update record via HTTP request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244803/create-or-update-record-via-http-request)  (Python/Jython).

Answer (score 3):

Your code is pretty solid. I so have a couple of minor tweaks.

> ```
> Function CodeName() As Worksheet
> Set CodeName = DataSheet
> End Function
> ```

This function is just adding a layer obfuscation.   You should just change the worksheets code name.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> will Open the Folder Explorer
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

From here you can change the Worksheet's Name property.

[image: Change the Worksheets Codename]

Combining lines should be avoided. It detracts from the readability of the code.  I am not opposed to declaring a variable and initiating its value in one line but only because you are allowed to assign values when declaring variables in most other languages.

Dim Target as Range: Set Target = Sheet1.Range("A1")

Here you are combing two actions into a single line.  Not only does it make it harder to read but it may run into problems later on when you are writing similar code.

> .Open "GET", url, False: .Send

Consider for instance that weeks down the you are having problems writing a new function because you forgot to `.Send` your request.  So what do you do?  You reference your code base.  Combing the `.Open` and `.Send` request into one line makes it hard to distinguish the ↑code above↑  from the ↓code below↓.

> .Open "GET", url, False

Although you never asked about speed I think its worth mentioning.

Adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the beginning of your code will make it run considerably faster.

Setting the `varAsync` parameter of the `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.Open()` method to True will allow the rest of the code to run while the HTTP `XMLHTTP.Request()` is processing.  This will allow you to create more connections.  Having 50 or more connections processing at once will greatly sped up the code.

> Sub open(bstrMethod As String, bstrUrl As String, [varAsync],
> [bstrUser], [bstrPassword])

---

[image: Object Browser]

In my answers to the questions below I create a connection pool.  I initiate the pool with x number of connections.  As the requests are completed the newly freed connection is given a new request.

Shameless plug:

- [Data scraping from Internet with Excel-VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210404/171419)
- [Retrieve data from eBird API and create multi-level hierarchy of locations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196922/171419)

In truth, setting up a connection pool, is probably over kill.  But it is nice to know that it can be done in case you every need the extra speed boast.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a follow-up question here: [Create or update record via HTTP request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244803/create-or-update-record-via-http-request).