# Part 1: Create or update record via HTTP request

Tags: python, python-2.x, http, jython

Update:

This is an older version of the question/script. The new version can be found here: [Part 2: Create or update record via HTTP request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245073/part-2-create-or-update-record-via-http-request?noredirect=1#comment481239_245073)

---

I have an [external system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244736/part-2-send-http-request-for-each-row-in-excel-table/244756) that sends an HTTP request to a Jython script (in IBM's [Maximo Asset Management](https://www.ibm.com/ca-en/marketplace/maximo) platform).

The Jython 2.7.0 script does this:

1. Accepts an HTTP request: `http://server:port/maximo/oslc/script/CREATEWO?_lid=wilson&_lpwd=wilson&f_wonum=LWO0382&f_description=LEGACY WO&f_classstructureid=1666&f_status=APPR&f_wopriority=1&f_assetnum=LA1234&f_worktype=CM`
2. Loops through parameters:

   - Searches for parameters that are prefixed with `f_` (*'f'* is for field-value)
   - Puts the parameters in a list
   - Removes the prefix from the list values (so that the parameter names match the database field names).
3. Updates or creates records via the parameters in the list:

   - If there is an existing record in the system with the same work order number, then the script updates the exiting record with the parameter values from the list.
   - If there isn't an existing record, then a new record is created (again, from the parameter values from the list).
4. Finishes by returning a message to the external system (message: updated, created, or other (aka an error)).

Can the script be improved?

---

```
from psdi.mbo import SqlFormat
from psdi.server import MXServer
from psdi.mbo import MboSet

params = list( param for param in request.getQueryParams() if param.startswith('f_') )
paramdict={} 
resp='' 
for p in params:
    paramdict[p[2:]]=request.getQueryParam(p)

woset = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("workorder",request.getUserInfo())

#Prevents SQL injection
sqf = SqlFormat("wonum=:1")
sqf.setObject(1,"WORKORDER","WONUM",request.getQueryParam("f_wonum"))

woset.setWhere(sqf.format())

woset.reset()
woMbo = woset.moveFirst()

if woMbo is not None:
    for k,v in paramdict.items():
        woMbo.setValue(k,v,2L)
    resp = 'Updated workorder ' + request.getQueryParam("f_wonum")
    woset.save()
    woset.clear()
    woset.close()
else:
    woMbo=woset.add()
    for k,v in paramdict.items():
        woMbo.setValue(k,v,2L)
    resp = 'Created workorder ' + request.getQueryParam("f_wonum")
    woset.save()
    woset.clear()
    woset.close()
responseBody = resp
```

---

<sup>*Note 1: Previously, there was an SQL injection vulnerability in the code. This issue has been resolved via the [SQLFormat java class](https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/psdi/mbo/SqlFormat.html). The code has been updated.*</sup>

<sup>*Note 2: Unfortunately, I'm **not** able to import Python 2.7.0 libraries into my Jython implementation. In fact, I don't even have access to all of the standard python libraries.*</sup>

<sup>*Note 3: The acronym 'MBO' stands for 'Master Business Object' (it's an IBM thing). For the purpose of this question, a Master Business Object can be thought of as a work order **record**. Additionally, the [constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446491/maximo-what-is-the-purpose-of-maxvars) ***2L*** tells the system to override any MBO rules/constraints.*</sup>

Comment: You should read: [Preventing SQL Injection Attacks With Python](https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/).  If you cannot use the sql library from the article then I would Google: "Regex to Prevent SQL Injection".

Comment: Ensuring that `f_wonum` `isNumeric()` will prevent the SQL attacks for this script, assuming that `f_wonum` is a number.

Comment: @TinMan Thanks. Actually, `f_wonum` is not a number. What I've done is utilized the [SQLFormat Java class](https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/psdi/mbo/SqlFormat.html) for this. I've updated *Note 1* in the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can the script be improved?

Jython is somewhat of a horror show, so improvements are limited but still possible.

### List comprehensions

```
params = list( param for param in request.getQueryParams() if param.startswith('f_') )
```

can be

```
params = [
    param for param in request.getQueryParams()
    if param.startswith('f_')
]
```

### Dict comprehensions

This just [squeaked into Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#implementation):

```
paramdict = {
    p[2:]: request.getQueryParam(p)
    for p in params
}
```

### Factor out common code

Factor out common code from these blocks:

```
if woMbo is not None:
    for k,v in paramdict.items():
        woMbo.setValue(k,v,2L)
    resp = 'Updated workorder ' + request.getQueryParam("f_wonum")
    woset.save()
    woset.clear()
    woset.close()
else:
    woMbo=woset.add()
    for k,v in paramdict.items():
        woMbo.setValue(k,v,2L)
    resp = 'Created workorder ' + request.getQueryParam("f_wonum")
    woset.save()
    woset.clear()
    woset.close()
```

For example,

```
if woMbo is None:
    woMbo=woset.add()
    verb = 'Created'
else:
    verb = 'Updated'

for k,v in paramdict.items():
    woMbo.setValue(k,v,2L)
resp = verb + ' workorder ' + request.getQueryParam("f_wonum")
woset.save()
woset.clear()
woset.close()
```

### Guaranteed closure

Wrap your code in a `try`/`finally`:

```
woset = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("workorder",request.getUserInfo())
try:
    # ...
finally:
    woset.close()
```

### Named constants

> the constant `2L` tells the system to override any MBO rules/constraints

Fine; so it should get first-class treatment:

```
IGNORE_RULES = 2L
```