# Part 2: Create or update record via HTTP request

Tags: python, python-2.x, http, jython

This script was previously reviewed here: [Part 1: Create or update record via HTTP request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244803/part-1-create-or-update-record-via-http-request)

I've made the changes that were suggested by @Reinderien.

Now that the code has been significantly refactored, are there any other improvements that could be made?

---

Description:

I have an [external system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244736/part-2-send-http-request-for-each-row-in-excel-table/244756) that sends an HTTP request to a Jython script (in [IBM's Maximo Asset Management](https://www.ibm.com/ca-en/marketplace/maximo) platform).

The Jython 2.7.0 script does this:

1. Accepts an HTTP request: `http://server:port/maximo/oslc/script/CREATEWO?_lid=wilson&_lpwd=wilson&f_wonum=LWO0382&f_description=LEGACY WO&f_classstructureid=1666&f_status=APPR&f_wopriority=1&f_assetnum=LA1234&f_worktype=CM`
2. Loops through parameters:

   - Searches for parameters that are prefixed with `f_` (*'f'* is for field-value)
   - Puts the parameters in a list
   - Removes the prefix from the list values (so that the parameter names match the database field names).
3. Updates or creates records via the parameters in the list:

   - If there is an existing record in the system with the same work order number, then the script updates the exiting record with the parameter values from the list.
   - If there isn't an existing record, then a new record is created (again, from the parameter values from the list).
4. Finishes by returning a message to the external system (message: updated, created, or other (aka an error)).

---

```
from psdi.mbo import SqlFormat
from psdi.server import MXServer
from psdi.mbo import MboSet

IGNORE_RULES = 2L

params = [
    param for param in request.getQueryParams()
    if param.startswith('f_')
]
paramdict = {
    p[2:]: request.getQueryParam(p)
    for p in params
}
resp='' 
woset = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("workorder",request.getUserInfo())

try:
    #Prevents SQL injection
    sqf = SqlFormat("wonum=:1")
    sqf.setObject(1,"WORKORDER","WONUM",request.getQueryParam("f_wonum"))
    woset.setWhere(sqf.format())
    woset.reset()
    woMbo = woset.moveFirst()

    if woMbo is None:
        woMbo=woset.add()
        verb = 'Created'
    else:
        verb = 'Updated'

    for k,v in paramdict.items():
        woMbo.setValue(k,v,2L)
    resp = verb + ' workorder ' + request.getQueryParam("f_wonum")
    woset.save()
    woset.clear()
    woset.close()
finally:
    woset.close()

responseBody = resp
```

Comment: I have rolled back your edit since it invalidates an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't used this:

```
IGNORE_RULES
```

in your call to `setValue`.

Also, you have a double call to `close`; delete the first one.

`resp` does not benefit from being pre-initialized to an empty string; you can delete that line.

The only other thing I see is that this:

```
params = [
    param for param in request.getQueryParams()
    if param.startswith('f_')
]
paramdict = {
    p[2:]: request.getQueryParam(p)
    for p in params
}
```

can be condensed to only the dictionary comprehension:

```
paramdict = {
    p[2:]: request.getQueryParam(p)
    for p in request.getQueryParams()
    if p.startswith('f_')
}
```